Why does $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 1$?
I am trying to evaluate the limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right).
$$
Here is my reasoning:

As $x \to \infty$, we know that $\frac{1}{x^2} \to 0$.
From the standard limit property, we have:

$$
\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = 1.
$$
To rewrite the original limit, I let $y = \frac{1}{x^2}$, so $y \to 0^+$ as $x \to \infty$. Substituting this into the expression:
$$
x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \frac{\sin(y)}{y}.
$$
Using the known limit $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = 1$, I conclude that:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 1.
$$
I can't find a definition of the limit of composite functions that includes infinity as a cluster point.
Thank you for your help!

Besides lacking visibility, your question is not completely clear. There is no "definition of the limit of composite functions", be it "includes infinity as a cluster point" or not. Only definitions of limits, and theorems about the limit of composite functions.

You can always use the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of limits to verify but since you mention limits of composite functions, here's another way.
The main problem is $\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$, that is $\infty$ is not a part of our domain. It'd be easier to work with a system that included the infinities.
Take $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ to be the compactification of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty, -\infty\}$.
That is put on it the topology induced by the metric:
$d_{\overline{R}}(x,y) = |tan^{-1}(x)-tan^{-1}(y)|$
Define
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{sin(x)}{x} & x \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}\\
1 & x = 0\\
\end{cases}$$
and
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^2} & x \in \mathbb{R}\\
0 & x \in \{+\infty,-\infty\}\\
\end{cases}
$$
You can verify now that $f$ is continuous and you are after $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f \circ g(x) $. By continuity of $f$ we have
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f \circ g(x) = f( \lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x)) = f(0) = 1$$

$-\infty$ is irrelevant. You can take the compactification of $[0,\infty)$.

Yes! It's just easier for me at least to imagine the symmetric space.
